# How to SUM a range of cells in a column?

Tags: excel, vba

This is tied to a function call in a different worksheet:

```
WorkSheets("Individual").Activate
Range("T6").End(xlDown).NumberFormat = "0.00"

Dim Total as Double
Total = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("T6"), Range("T6").End(xlDown)))

MsgBox CStr(Total)
```

It returns "0" when I've populated test values of 10 and 15 in cells T7 & T8.

My intention is to sum the active range of values from T6 (the header) downwards.

As a test I added the below two lines:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("T7").Select
MsgBox ActiveCell.Value
```

Which correctly returns 10.

Comment: What is the result of this formula entered into the immediate window:  `?worksheetfunction.IsText([T7])`

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Check 4th line.

```
WorkSheets("Individual").Activate
Range("T6").End(xlDown).NumberFormat = "0.00"

Dim Total as Double
Total = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Range("T6"), Range("T6").End(xlDown)))

MsgBox CStr(Total)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
WorkSheets("Individual").Activate
Range("T6").End(xlDown).NumberFormat = "0.00"

Dim Total as Double
Total = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("T6").End(xlDown))

MsgBox CStr(Total)
```

If that doesn't work, try:

```
WorkSheets("Individual").Activate
Range("T6").End(xlDown).NumberFormat = "0.00"

Dim Total as Double

Dim rEnd as range
rEnd = Range("T6").End(xlDown).Address
rSelect = "T6:" & rEnd
Total = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(rSelect))

MsgBox CStr(Total)
```

Or try the second one with this line slightly modified, like so:

```
Total = WorksheetFunction.Sum(rSelect)
```